# DataTable.Select string/int comparison

Tags: c#, datatable

I got crazy finding a reason with my grid don't show correctly and found that I compare a varchar column (of only numeric values) without using ' (quote).
The problem is that for some numbers the select match and for other the select don't match.

This is an example:

```
DataTable tab = new DataTable();
tab.Columns.Add("age", typeof(String));
DataRow row1 = tab.NewRow();
row1["age"] = "8";
tab.Rows.Add(row1);
DataRow row2 = tab.NewRow();
row2["age"] = "15";
tab.Rows.Add(row2); 

Console.WriteLine("Rows with age 8="+ tab.Select("age=8").Length);
Console.WriteLine("Rows with age 15=" + tab.Select("age=15").Length);
```

Output is:

```
Rows with age 8=0
Rows with age 15=1
```

Why for 8 number don't match and for 15 number yes? Is this a bug?

Comment: I think both should not match, it's strange that the `15` is matched?

Comment: Stranger yet, alter the number from 15 in the second statement, the first will say it's true

Comment: I think you may have to use single quotes for string comparassing

Comment: @Yuriy is correct, but this is still strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug (feature?) in internal string/int comparassing. You have to either add single quotes to compare data as strings, or if you need to compare them as integers and you're open to use LINQ you can do something like

```
int i = tab.AsEnumerable().Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["age"]) == 8).Count(); // 1
```